# Postgres: Materialized View Refresh Taking Longer Than Creation

Tags: sql, postgresql, materialized-views, postgresql-11

I have query that takes about 4 minutes to run but the underlying data doesn't change throughout the day so I created a materialized view. I use materialized views in postgres regularly so I thought this would be super simple, however, the view refresh doesn't seem to be working the way I expected.

The creation took about 4 minutes to run, as expected, but when I call the refresh command it runs for hours. I thought maybe it was due to table locks but the query executes fine on it's own so I didn't see why that would cause any issues with the refresh.

Are there server setting that dictates how materialized views are created vs refreshed?

I'm not really sure where to look next so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing using the option `WITH NO DATA`?

Comment: are you refreshing concurrently?

Comment: @GordonLinoff refreshing using WITH NO DATA does run but the refresh to populate the data afterwards still runs forever.

Comment: @Jeremy no I am not refreshing concurrently

Comment: @Anepicpastry . . . Are other processes reading from the MV while you are attempting the refresh?

Comment: @GordonLinoff    No there are not. I copied the view into a different schema just to be sure and the refresh didn't work on the copy either.

Comment: Can you provide a simple reproducible test case?  i.e. show the table creation, populate the table with random data, show the materialized view creation.

Comment: @Jeremy I am facing the same issue and I am refreshing concurrently. how does refreshing concurrently affects the refreshing, what might cause it to get stuck?

Comment: I observed this problem while creating the MV in one session and tried to refresh it from other session. After closing the first session the *hang* dissapears.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I just ran into this exact same issue with a materialized view on Postgres 12. Creating the view would only take a few seconds, but it would take hours to refresh it.

My solution ended up being to run `VACCUM ANALYZE;` After doing that, refreshing the view was fast again.